# UIscrollview initial image size

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am new to objective-c I am building an app that has a scrollable image but can't get the initial image size to fit the start view at 320 x 411 when the tab is selected, as this is for predominantly medical images the user will need to have an overview and the ability to zoom in on a detail. So the intention is to have the initial image at 30% zoom rather than 100%.

I have pasted the code below any help would be appreciated

I have attached a screen shot showing the problem where only part of the flowchart is shown when the tab is selected.I want the whole flowchart to be shown when the tab is selected.

[image]

**From AlgorithmViewController.h file**

```
@interface AlgorithmViewController : UIViewController {

UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
```

**From AlgorithmViewController.m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"photo1.jpg"];
    imageView = [[ UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [(UIScrollView *)self.view setContentSize:[image size]];
    [(UIScrollView *)self.view setMaximumZoomScale:2.0];
    [(UIScrollView *)self.view setMinimumZoomScale:0.4];
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here ? It seems difficult to find out problem from your question

Comment: Check the value your [image size] returns. And if you post screenshots it would be clearer to us. Or explain further as to what the issue is. Its difficult to understand your problem from this description.

Comment: You say the image is supposed to be scrollable, then why do you want it to fit in the screen? Then what is the need for the scroll?

Answer (score 0):

add scaleToSize to your UIImage

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"photo1.jpg"] scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 411)];
```

and

```
[(UIScrollView *)self.view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 411)];
```

Answer (score 0):

program comes up with an error "UIImage may not respond to scaleToSize".
Solved excellent tutorial on the subject at

http://cocoadevblog.com/iphone-tutorial-uiimage-with-zooming-tapping-rotation